# Selecting columns by conditions in pandas

Tags: pandas, csv, dataframe

This is my dataframe:

https://ibb.co/z6RKtYt

I want to pick up the "entire home" in "manhattan" for a price between 150 and 175.
How can I select this THREE conditions?

Answer (score 1):

I can't really see the whole variable names in the snapshot, but barring any problems with that this should work:

```
df[(df.neighborhood == 'Manhattan') & (df.room_type == 'Entire home') & (df.price.between(150, 175)]
```

Comment: It gaves me
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: That's why you should always provide a subset of your data so that we can try and see things like the column data type, which is clearly the issue here. Is the `price` column numeric? You can check with `df.price.dtype`. If the answer is `object` or something other than a numeric type, then you can transform it like this: `df.price = df.price.astype(float)`. Then the code above should work. If it doesn't, please provide the whole error message, so I can see what column(s) the problem is in.

Comment: U were right!
Price was an object and now a float.
But in this way I discovered that my dataframe is messy because the new error message is:

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Private room'
(whole error msg is too long to put here)

So I guess that inside the column price there are some null values and some not inerent values like "private room". I should drop this values...

Comment: Yes, it looks like your dataset needs some cleaning before you can do what you want.